Retry request until API returns proper value then continue with further requests
I need to retry particular request in Postman to wait until task will be unlocked.
I don't know how long it will take, it may be from 1 sec up to 1min.
Below script seems to not always be working due to asynchronous behaviour.
What kind of solution would you recommend here?
function checkIfTaskIsLocked(responseJson) {
    if(responseJson.items && responseJson.items(taskId) {
    if (responseJson.items[taskId].isLocked === false {
    return true;
    } else {
        console.log("task is locked");
        return false
    }
} else {
    console.log("task not found")
    return false;
}
}

if(!checkIfTaskIsLocked(responseJson)) {
    console.log("retrying request")
    setTimeout(function() {
        pm.execution.setNextRequest(pm.info.requestName)
    }, 10000)
}


This should do:
var maxNumberOfTries = 12; // Retry up to 12 times
var sleepBetweenTries = 5000; // 5 seconds between tries

// Helper function to check if the task is locked
function checkIfTaskIsLocked(responseJson) {
    if (responseJson.items && responseJson.items[taskId]) {
        if (responseJson.items[taskId].isLocked === false) {
            return true;
        } else {
            console.log("Task is locked");
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        console.log("Task not found");
        return false;
    }
}

// Initialize or increment the retry count
if (!pm.environment.get("collection_tries")) {
    pm.environment.set("collection_tries", 1);
} else {
    var tries = parseInt(pm.environment.get("collection_tries"), 10);
    pm.environment.set("collection_tries", tries + 1);
}

// Check if the task is unlocked or if the maximum number of tries has been reached
if (!checkIfTaskIsLocked(responseJson) && pm.environment.get("collection_tries") < maxNumberOfTries) {
    console.log("Retrying request... Attempt: " + pm.environment.get("collection_tries"));
    setTimeout(function() {
        postman.setNextRequest(pm.info.requestName); // Retry the same request
    }, sleepBetweenTries);
} else {
    // Reset the retry count after success or reaching the max number of tries
    pm.environment.unset("collection_tries");

    // You can add tests or other logic here
    pm.test("Task unlocked or max retries reached", function() {
        pm.expect(checkIfTaskIsLocked(responseJson)).to.be.true;
    });
}


It's based on a solution, that I invented to only excute tests, if I get an ok answer: https://community.postman.com/t/retry-a-failing-request/5934

hello @Christian Baumann, thank you for your response. Your example is not working for me. I mean it is waiting properly for the task to be unlocked, but later on it is skipping next, subsequent request within collection for no reason.
